# Passing and Returning connection and cursor for Postgresql in Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I have written a connection.py file as follows :

```
from configparser import ConfigParser
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd


def get_section(a):
    section_dict = {
            1:'one_db',
            2:'two_db',
            3:'three_db'
            }
    return section_dict.get(a)

def config(a):

    filename='config.ini',
    section=get_section(a)
    # create a parser
    parser = ConfigParser()
    # read config file
    parser.read(filename)

    # get section, default to postgresql
    db = {}
    if parser.has_section(section):
        params = parser.items(section)
        for param in params:
            db[param[0]] = param[1]
    else:
        raise Exception('Section {0} not found in the {1} file'.format(section, filename))

    return db

def get_data(query,a):
    """ Connect to the PostgreSQL database server """

    connection = None
    try:
        # read connection parameters
        params = config(a)

        # connect to the PostgreSQL server
        print('Connecting to '+ get_section(a) )
        connection = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        print('Connected')

        # create a cursor
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        cursor.execute(query)
        df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
        colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]
        df.columns = colnames
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        print('Closing connection...')
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print('Connection closed')

    return df
```

I use the get_data function in different places to get data from database as follows

```
from connection import get_data
query = "some_query"
df = get_data(query,1)
```

It is working fine. But at places I have to use many queries continuously one by one and get data. The problem with this structure is each time it connects and disconnects. So if i have ten queries in one file , connecting and disconnecting happens ten times.**How do I modify the code such that I can have the following format :**

```
connect(1)
df1 = get_data(query1)
df2 = get_data(query2)
df3 = get_data(query3)
.
.
.
.
.
.
disconnect()
```

The number 1 or 2 or 3 in connect(x) is that i have three databases to chose. I hope I am clear with the problem. Ready to share any other details as well.

I tried the following, but not sure if it is complete or not:
*Use get_data function where you return cur and con. I have made the following changes in connection.py*

```
def get_connection(a):
    """ Connect to the PostgreSQL database server """

    connection = None
    try:
        # read connection parameters
        params = config(a)

        # connect to the PostgreSQL server
        print('Connecting to '+ get_section(a) )
        connection = psycopg2.connect(**params)
        print('Connected')

        # create a cursor
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        return (connection,cursor)
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)

def get_data(cursor,query):
    xcurs.execute(query)
    df = pd.DataFrame(xcurs.fetchall())
    colnames = [desc[0] for desc in xcurs.description]
    df.columns = colnames
    return df
```

Now in any file i do this:

```
conn,curs = get_connection(1)
df1 = get_data(curs,query1)
df2= get_data(curs,query2)
df3 = get_data(curs,query3)
df4 = get_data(curs,query4)
df5 = get_data(curs,query5)
.
.
.
.
.
curs.close()
conn.close()
```

**Is this method correct?**

Answer (score 0):

There are several solutions in psycopg2 out of the box. You need to get any implementation of [Connection Pool abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connection_pool) (i.e psycopg2.pool.SimpleConnectionPool) and use it's `getconn()` method to get connection.

```py
pool = SimpleConnectionPool(**params)

def get_data():
    connection = pool.getconn()
```